# Installing the intl extension with docker for php takes too long

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, icu

I use Alpine php image in docker, for my work I need the intl library, but its installation as an extension for php takes too long, long it is ~30 minutes for 2 images through the pipeline on version (23.*.*) of docker and ~ 17 minutes on the version (25.*.*) and for me it's just overhead, I don't understand the reason for such a long build.
Here is an example of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

ADD --chmod=0755 https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN install-php-extensions intl
```

Or if you want an older version:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache icu-dev icu-data-full \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl
```

And if you look at the size of the packages pulled by the apk, they don't weigh that much to install such a colossal amount of time: 
`icu-dev` - https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/icu-dev 
`icu-data-full` - https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/icu-data-full

Who has encountered this problem or knows how to solve/help the script to work more smoothly at least once again in x2, because it looks as strange as possible and it should not be like this, maybe it is possible to somehow compile the files and add them directly to the php extension, I will be glad and love suggestions.

P.S. - On a local machine, it will take an average of ~5 minutes, which is also impractically long

Comment: You could create your own image with php:8.2-fpm-alpine + intl and others pkgs, then push it to some docker registry. Next time, you'll pull your image with all stuff already installed

Comment: `docker-php-ext-install` compiles from source, so you're incurring the cost to download and install the compiler package and all of its related tools, and then compile the package, on every build. I'd definitely take @Mate's suggestion, and save a pre-made image of your build environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I'm concerned about is the build time, the build time won't change if I push it somewhere on dockerhub or my own repository, what I'm concerned about is judging by the question why it's taking so long, because it shouldn't take that long.

Comment: Yes, build time changes. Why you use php:8.2-fpm-alpine instead of use alpine and then  install php ?  There are a large number of variables that can impact the installation time of each package.  The same thing happened to me with Kafka. You save a lot of build time, and even more, you already have the image downloaded in case you reuse it